# How to create Popovers with Xcode Storyboards

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

How can I create a popover in an iPad Storyboard for an iOS 5.0+ app?

There's already one setup with the Xcode Project Template (Utility App), but I can't seem to figure out how Apple got it to work. I tried to mimic it, but only got errors. I even looked on Apple's Dev Site, but only got out-dated code that resulted in warnings and build errors.

I have a `CBMainView` and a `CBMasterView` (with the exception of the master view already included), and a `UIToolbar` with a `UIToolbarButton`. I need the user to tap the button on the `UIToolbar`, and up comes my 320x300 Popover (`CBMasterView`).

How can I do this with Xcode Storyboards? Tutorials, answers, code, or links are all appreciated!

Comment: I suggest still keeping Popover to their own .xib files. Storyboards can get too big sometimes. This happened to me and I ended up moving all my popovers to xib files and the performance when in my Storyboard is much better. It was extremely laggy before, and I have a very good MBP

Comment: @RyanG The size of your storyboard file should not affect runtime performance (although it may affect the speed of Xcode). If large storyboards significantly affect your runtime performance you should file a [bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn). You could also ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Before iOS 5, one would've needed to display another `UIViewController` using the First  Responder via a Modal presentation (and a pile of code).

To create a popover in Xcode's Storyboard Mode (iOS 5+) use a `UIButton` or `UIToolbarButton` and create a Storyboard Segue between the button and the `UIViewController` that you want to *pop-over*.

Creating a segue between a button and another `UIViewController` is simple. Here's how:

1. Click on the button in your storyboard and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Drag</kbd> from the button to the `UIViewController` of choice. You should see a light blue line appear that extends from the button to the tip of your mouse.
2. After dragging the blue line to the ViewController of choice a small black menu will appear. This menu displays the different segue options. Select `Popover`.

   [image: Popover Segue Menu]
3. If everything was done correctly, this segue should be visible in the Connections Inspector when the button is selected:

[image: Use Popover instead of Modal or Push]

The `UIViewController` you create should also have a custom size that is smaller than the full screen. You can set a custom size by selecting the View Controller and setting its size property to `freeform`, or `master` (320 x 850).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for the answer to this problem. I did solve it using NSNotification.

Here's how:

The View Controller that displays the popup should register to receive the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(languageSetup) name:SPVWChangeLanguage object:nil];
```

`languageSetup` is the function that will be called, `SPVWChangeLanguage` is a string that you will define in your popup view controller

I added this line in `viewDidAppear`

Now in your popup view controller add this line when the user selects something in the table:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: [NSNotification notificationWithName: SPVWChangeLanguage object:self]];
```

before dismissing the popup:

```
[self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

That's all. The selector languageSetup (in my case) will be called. Be sure to remove the notification when your view controller goes away:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

I do it in `viewWillDisappear`

I think there must be an easier way. But at least, this one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard with IOS8, take a look at this post, answered it for me!

[How to present a modal atop the current view in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336187/how-to-present-a-modal-atop-the-current-view-in-swift/25325168#25325168)

In short: You make a separate popup view, give the background a color with low (or none) opacity, and connect from your main view to the popup view, with a modal segue.

Then in storyboard, click on the segue, and then in the attibute inspector: change presentation to "over current context" (and maybe transition to cross dissolve, if you use an opacity that is more than 0)

Easiest way i have seen so far!