# Possible to present UIView without UIViewController in UIPopoverController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is it possible to quickly present a `UIView` in a `UIPopoverController` without having a `UIViewController` managing the `UIView`?

Currently I have a "`DelegateViewController`" that gets my view passed. Then I use that controller for presentation. But I'm wondering if there is an easier way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a `UIView`, then you can easily create a plain `UIViewController` as a container.

```
UIViewController* controller = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
controller.view = myView;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to quickly present a UIView in a UIPopoverController
>   without having a UIViewController managing the UIView?

**No.** UIPopoverController manages a view controller, not a view. When you create a popover controller, you have to provide the view controller that will manage the content. That doesn't mean that you have to create a special view controller subclass in every place where you use a popover -- as bendytree points out, you can use a plain old UIViewController if you want. But you can't just pass UIPopoverController a view -- it has no way to accept it, and wouldn't know what to do with it if did.

Answer (score 0):

It usually makes sense to have a `UIViewController` for a view since the controller handles all the interaction and setting up of the view. Although you can in some situations put "naked" views on screen the `UIPopoverController` is designed to work with a `UIViewController` and the ViewController paradigm is very well established and encouraged in the iOS world, so even if you think you don't seem to need a view controller it should not be harmful to have one and you might always want to extend the current functionality, right?

Please Note: If you are on iOS 5.0 creating views in Popovers is very simple and a matter of dragging-and-dropping the view controllers and hooking them up on the storyboard. Example: [How to create Popovers with Xcode Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249085/how-to-create-popovers-with-a-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2)