# How to present a custom modal in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I don't know how can I do that in Xcode , maybe with the Interface Builder or programmaticaly ?

I want to display a modal like this :

[image]

I can do that with pods but I want to create my own modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always make this kind of modals in Storyboard. Give the view of the view controller a black background color, with an alpha lower than 1. Also make sure the `modalPresentationStyle` is set to Over Current Context.

Comment: I create another viewcontroller and present it with segue ??

Comment: Can you explain me how to present this modal ?

Comment: Yes, you can make a segue, and present it modally. Or you can do it in code with self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil).

Comment: I'm trying but I get this http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/669058Capturede769cran20160725a768210924.png and I use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336187/how-to-present-a-modal-atop-the-current-view-in-swift to create but not working I think

Comment: Make sure you use Over Current Context, not Current Context.